# ImportError: No module named 'ruamel_yaml' after conda update --all

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Ran

```
conda update --all
```

which completed. Afterwards, when doing anything in conda it throws an error

```
ImportError: No module named 'ruamel_yaml'
```

Output of `echo $PATH`

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/Users/*username*/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/fsl/bin:/opt/spark/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin
```

and `which conda` outputs

```
/Users/*username*/anaconda/bin/conda
```

If I do `pip install ruamel.yaml` i get

```
Requirement already satisfied: ruamel.yaml in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: ruamel.ordereddict; platform_python_implementation == "CPython" and python_version <= "2.7" in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ruamel.yaml)
```

Comment: Is `conda` using the same installation of Python as `pip`?

Comment: Dont know how to check that. `which python` returns `/Users/*username*/anaconda/bin/python`while `which pip`returns `/usr/local/bin/pip`.

Comment: While I install a few Pythons to doublecheck, just view those files in  a text editor or through `less`. My hunch is the path to their "mother" python will be in the `#!` line in them.

Comment: Exactly what files am I supposed to look at?

Comment: The ones you just mentioned and that you mention in your OP, the `conda` script and the `pip` script you're actually executing.

Comment: like literally run `less $(which conda)` and `less $(which pip)`

Comment: Alright, so I did check paths for pip, conda and several other packages and for some reason it was a total cluster f***. Reinstalled anaconda and I can't reproduce the error. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Had a similar issue pop up just recently. Guessing what happened is something like: Conda uses its own Python installation, but installed some libraries using `pip` on the PATH, which happened to catch the system installation of Python. But the general pattern is: if Python program `foo` is mysteriously complaining about a missing library; when a different Python program `bar` can find the library just fine; then it’s probably because they use two different installations of Python.

Comment: And it’s the default behaviour of Python programs that their launcher scripts point, using an absolute path, to the Python installation they belong to. Most of the time this should lead to consistent behaviour rather than breakage, since the set of available libraries for an end program should remain stable, while a developer installation of Python will have stuff changing around it a lot, but Stuff Happens. I should at some point make a self-answered question that addresses this problem, to point at it as a dupe when investigating a manifestation of this issue shows it is in fact that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer, but for some reason several packages in anaconda had changed paths after running `conda update --all` to native OSx python. The damage was beyond manual correction, so I completely rewarped anaconda.

I can't reproduce this behaviour after having removed anaconda entirely, and run `conda update --all` again.

see @millimoose comments for a deeper explanation.